# Masking Image Only Fast If Opposite Ordering?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a large medical image with dimensions `(512, 512, 400)`. I also have a binary image with dimensions `(512, 512, 400)` which identifies which voxels in the image belong to the Bladder (1=belongs to bladder, 0=does not belong to bladder).

I want to get the average value of the bladder.

This works and is pretty fast (<1 second):

```
bladder = image_arr[mask_arr > 0]
bladder_avg = np.mean(bladder)
```

In this scenario, `image_arr` is F-contiguous, and `mask_arr` is C-contiguous. Here's the problem: if I make `make_arr` also be F-contiguous, then the above operation is *much* slower (7+ seconds). It still comes up with the right answer though.

I want `mask_arr` to be F-contiguous for later when I serialize it (because the serializer is optimized for F-contiguous). Interestingly, as long as the two arrays have opposite memory ordering (CF or FC), it is fast. But if they have the same ordering (CC or FF) it's extremely slow.

Anyone know what's going on here? This is very un-intuitive. If I were doing this in C++ I would think same-ordering would be optimal because you could share loop index and take advantage of caching better.

Comment: As you want to do the conversion to F-order at some point anyway, why don't you do it after computing your mean? Also, are you sure that the total time of the serialization is better than serialization from C-order when you include the time to convert to F-order?

Comment: Correct, if I do it after computing the mean, the conversion penalty cancels out the serialization savings. There does not seem to be a penalty if I just read it in as F-order from the very start, however, then computing the mean is extremely slow. It seems like this is just one of the problems with numpy - it's hard to directly control how it is storing and iterating your data.

Comment: What in the world... it seems CPU architecture matters. The problem goes away and in fact there's a large performance boost if I switch to an Intel CPU (vs. AMD) when switching the binary iamge to F-ordering. Guessing this is a MKL thing...

Comment: For me only the CC case ran in under a second, that is for a float64 image and uint8 mask. Any F ordering made it at least 2x slower. I tried this on both AMD (Zen 1 with single channel DDR4) and Intel (dual channel DDR3). Maybe it's due to the version of numpy, or how it was compiled?